# Download Manager failing the valid url for download

Tags: android

I am downloading following url using DownloadManager:

```
http://dc110.4shared.com/img/359248229/582f60e/dlink__2Fdownload_2FZD6Dl4G9_3Ftsid_3D20140110-51601-2fd92fa0/preview.mp3
```

If you hit it inside browser, you will find it is valid. But Download Manager is failing it. Any ideas?

Comment: post your download manger code

Comment: @NitinMisra My download service: http://pastie.org/8620107

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error with 4shared, when I check the DownloaderManager COLUMN_REASON i get error 1002 and Android Developer says:

> Value of COLUMN_REASON when an HTTP code was received that download
>   manager can't handle.

[Android Developer info](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html)

Comment: I studied this and it was because the server is doing some redirection which DownloadManager can't handle.